# HAProxy & MeteorJS - 503 errors everywhere

Tags: haproxy

I'm trying to set up HAProxy as a load balance for two MeteorJS instances. For some reason, HAProxy does not seem to pick up that my instances are there. I can `curl 192.168.0.4` and I get the expected result, though, so I'm not sure how it can't find my instances? Also, I used [this](https://gist.github.com/fightingtheboss/5843330) as an inspiration.

Here's my HAProxy config:

```
global
  daemon

defaults
  mode http
  timeout connect 86400000
  timeout server 86400000
  timeout client 86400000
  timeout check 5s
  maxconn 2000

frontend http-in *:80
  #bind idle.land:80
  #bind 192.99.68.70:80
  default_backend idle_land
  acl is_api_idle_land hdr_end(host) -i api.idle.land
  acl is_idle_land hdr_end(host) -i idle.land

  tcp-request inspect-delay 500ms
  tcp-request content accept if HTTP

  use_backend api_idle_land if is_api_idle_land
  use_backend idle_land if is_idle_land

backend idle_land
  balance leastconn
  cookie SERVERID insert nocache indirect
  option forwardfor if-none
  option httpchk get /ping
  no option httpclose
  option http-server-close
  option forceclose

  server meteor1 192.168.0.2 check port 80 cookie meteor1
  server meteor2 192.168.0.4 check port 80 cookie meteor2


backend api_idle_land
  server api 192.168.0.5

listen stats *:1976
  mode http
  timeout client 5000
  timeout connect 5000
  timeout server 5000
  stats enable
  stats uri /
  stats hide-version
  stats auth admin:admin
  stats scope idle_land
```

(I've also asked this on [Ubuntu.SE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/547600/haproxy-meteor-503s) - I'm not sure where it's more relevant)

Comment: Does it work if you comment out the 'httpchk' line in your backend?

Comment: Yes. I also commented out a bunch of other things, though, so it could be anything. Unfortunately I'm still trying to figure out why Websockets aren't working, but that's a task for another day.

Comment: Can you browse to /ping on either of the backends in a browser?

Comment: Checking `/ping` just gives me the content of my index.

Comment: is there a reason you're requesting that path?  If that's not something you explicitly set up for monitoring, change the line to just read 'option httpchk'.

Comment: No, no reason in particular, I just found it in a guide that I was following. Honestly not sure what I'm doing, haha.

Comment: The 'get /ping' portion of the line specifies a specific path HAproxy should try to reach.  Sometimes it's desirable to host a specific page for monitoring.  If you're not doing that, leave it out and HAproxy will just try to get the root of the website.